# Ace Editor Live Preview

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I'm playing around with trying to create a live preview of ace editor of what's being typed into the editor.

I tried:

```
<pre id="editor"></pre>
<div id="return"></div>

<script src="vendor/ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>

<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function showHTML () {
        $('#return').html($('#editor').val());
    }
</script>
```

The editor works, but the live preview of what's being typed in the editor isn't. I can get it working for a textarea, but not the editor. What can I do to get the live preview working for the editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like showHTML is never called, try adding `editor.on("input", showHTML)`
and use `editor.getValue()` in showHTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
<style>
    html, body { height: 100% }
    #editor, #return { height: 50% }
</style>
  
<pre id="editor">xxx</pre>
<div id="return"></div>

<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

    function showHTML() {
        $('#return').html(editor.getValue());
    }
    // or use data: url to handle things like doctype
    function showHTMLInIFrame() {
        $('#return').html("<iframe src=" +
             "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue()) +
        "></iframe>");
    }
    editor.on("input", showHTMLInIFrame)
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything. I also tried: `editor.on("#editor", showHTML);`

Comment: Thanks, it works great, but I can't say I fully understand it. I'll have to review the code until I get it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto

```
 editor.session.on('change', function (delta) {
                        // delta.start, delta.end, delta.lines, delta.action
                    });
```